# "wasm decoding failResult" when app is packaged with electron-forge

Tags: electron, electron-forge

I am trying to package an electron app (that uses wasm) with electron-forge.

At the moment (while I fight packaging!) it's little more than a hello-world, but it compiles a simple rust lib to wasm, then I copy the .js and .wasm files into ./src/ and package as an electron app.

Running it using "electron-forge start" works perfectly, but when I package it with "electon-forge make" (to a DMG on Mac OS in this case) and then install and run it, it seems to be trying to load the wrong .wasm file (or it's been modified...) as I get these errors:

[image]

There is only one .wasm file bundled, and I have checked the .js that it has the reference to the correct file.

If I go into the .app package in /Applications and navigate to the packaged source files all is correct, and the same as my source folders.

Checking the magic number of the .wasm file also seems fine..

`hexdump ui-72b0082cbbe1a2b5.wasm |head -n 1
0000000 00 61 73 6d 01 00 00 00 01 86 01 13 60 02 7f 7f`

So, I don't know what file it's trying to load as .wasm and why the magic number is not correct.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you still have this problem, but this was stumping me for a while, so I figured I'd leave the answer for the next person. Short answer, you need to add a small bit to your json config file. Example:

**Default config:**

```
...
"config": {
   "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": { },
...
```

**Fixed config:**

```
...
"config": {
   "forge": {
      "packagerConfig": { "asar.unpack" : "yourFileHere.js" },
...
```

Best I can tell, the problem is coming from electron-packager and how it compresses everything into that asar file. It seems to try and serve the compressed file, so the MIME type is wrong. But even when I changed the web assembly loading code to use WebAssembly.instantiate instead of WebAssembly.instantiateStreaming (that avoids the MIME check), I was still left with those magic number issues...that was the clue that compression was the issue.

You can do directories also, info here about other packager options
https://github.com/electron/electron-packager/blob/master/docs/api.md#asar

Comment: Thanks, but the whole experience was so complicated and hard that i gave up on the whole electron approach, :-(